# Selenium IDE how to get a response from a api request

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am running an API request in Selenium IDE  but when I try to echo the response it appears as null. The payload works as expected but how to get the response information??

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var theUrl = "";
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("client_id", "");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("client_secret", "");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
    "header": {
        "correlationId": "",
        "eventName": "createCustomer"
    },
    "payload": [{
        "typeOfCustomer": 2,
        "samplingProgramCode": "samplingProgramCode",
        "firstname": "CPRichard82",
        "prefix": "Herr",
        "lastname": "CPKearney82",
        "birthdate": "1978-07-23",
        "healthInsuranceNumber": "",
        "dataPrivacy": 1,
        "termsAndConditions": 1,
        "videoTraining": 1,
        "signature": 1,
        "gender": 0,
        "email": "",
        "mobile": "+491510000000",
        "tel": "1554445454",
        "measurement": "mmol/l",
        "permissions": [{
            "communicationType": "Newsletter": 1
        }]
    }]
}));
var response = xmlhttp.status
```

Expected ok or 200

Comment: this really has nothing to do with selenium.  Maybe change the tags to http requests?  If you get "0", you may want to check readystate first.  If nothing, the server may not send a status code.

Comment: can you please give an example if you can?

Comment: You're expecting the response to be instant and the internet doesn't work like that. Also try fetch instead of xmlhttp, it's easier